# Generating Poisson-Gamma data for empirical parameter estimation in r

Tags: r, simulation, empirical-bayes

I'm currently trying to learn parameter estimation and want to illustrate and compare different credibility methods (limited fluctuation, Bühlmann, Bühlmann-Straub) using both Bayesian and Empirical parameter estimation (non-parametric, semi-parametric, fully parametric).

What I am having trouble with is generating my own data using a Poisson-Gamma in R. For example, if $X_{ij}|\Theta_i$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\Theta_i$ where $\Theta$ is gamma distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I want to generate $r$ ($i=1,...,r$) policyholders for $n$ ($j=1,...,n$) years but also want to be able to add past exposures $m_{ij}$ for some simulations but I'm unsure how to code this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I believe I've worked it out but I'm not entirely sure. Below is my code. I am still confused on whether or not I am doing the replications correct. I originally had the first set of code but thought I should keep $\Theta_i$ consistent and also found the function rgpois from the extraDistr package. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(5)

reps <- 200 # number of replications
n <- 4 # number of periods
r <- 3 # sample size

i <- j <- 1
gam <- rgamma(reps, 24, 10) # generating theta_i

x <- data.frame()
y <- c()

for(i in 1:reps) {
  y <- rpois(n, gam[i])
    for(j in 1:n) {
      x[i,j] <- y[j]
  }
}
colnames(x) <- c("Year 1","Year 2","Year 3","Year 4")
head(x)

x.sample <- sample_n(x, size = r)
x.sample
```

I also removed the rgamma and replaced rpois from the above code with the rgpois function.

````
library(dplyr)
set.seed(5)

reps <- 200 # number of replications
n <- 4 # number of periods
r <- 3 # sample size

i <- j <- k <- 1
gam <- rgamma(r, 24, 10) # generating theta_i

x <- data.frame()
y <- c()

for(i in 1:reps){
  for(j in 1:3){
    y <- rpois(n, gam[j])
    for(k in 1:n) {
      x[3*(i-1)+j,k] <- y[k]
    }
  }
}

colnames(x) <- c("Year 1","Year 2","Year 3","Year 4")
head(x)

x.sample <- rdunif(1,1,100)
x.sample
xx.sample <- rbind(x[3*x.sample-2,], x[3*x.sample-1,], x[3*x.sample,])
xx.sample
```
````

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "add past exposures for some simulations"?

Comment: For instance an insurance policy may be a group policy that covers many individuals and the number of individuals may change each period. Therefore the amount of exposures may be 60 the first period but 68 the second period etc.

Comment: But how exactly does that fit into the general setting you describe?

Comment: It is not required but I wanted to try and generate data so I could run a simulation using the Bühlmann-Straub method which handles past exposures.